# Page is still authenticated after gitlab is logout

Tags: php, symfony, oauth-2.0, gitlab, symfony5

I am using **KnpUOAuth2ClientBundle** for **Symfony 5**. When I enter the page, if user is not logged, then it redirects to gitlab page and on authentication it successfully redirects to my homepage where it stores cookie.

But after I logout gitlab and check my homepage, it still works as cookie is stored.

This seems to be error. What should I do so that if gitlab is logout, the cookie is cleared.

This is my `security.yaml` file

```
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            id: App\Security\UserProvider
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: true
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\GitlabAuthenticator
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/connect, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

I am not sure what I am trying to do is correct or not. Inside GitlabAuthController I have connectAction method where I am trying to clear the cookie set

```
  public function connectAction(ClientRegistry $clientRegistry): RedirectResponse
    {
        if ($this->logout()->getStatusCode() === 200) {
            // will redirect to gitlab!
            return $clientRegistry
                ->getClient('gitlab') // key used in config/packages/knpu_oauth2_client.yaml
                ->redirect()
                ;
        }
    }

public function logout()
    {
        $response = new Response();
        $response->headers->clearCookie('PHPSESSID');
        return $response->send();
    }
```

But with this one I am getting `Invalid state parameter passed in callback URL.` error.

Comment: Browser is not the server.

Comment: What does that mean @MarkusZeller

Comment: Your browser has different sessions and cookies than the server running Symfony.

Comment: @MarkusZeller I tried something like clearout the cookie when page render but it is giving me some other error. I have updated the question

Comment: Again, the server running Symfony has no impact on your Browsers cookies on a different site, like Gitlab.

Comment: So what should I do? I am working on my local

Comment: Simply, you can't.

Answer (score 2):

## explanation

Your Symfony uses gitlab as an authentication provider (as in: "I don't want to handle logins myself, and I don't want to store passwords"). This implies however, that symfony and gitlab do not share the same session. Logging out of gitlab doesn't mean anything to your symfony site and vice versa. So what you describe as "This seems to be error" (sic) actually is exactly the expected behavior.

What you apparently want is to somehow merge both sessions.

The following answer is of theoretical nature and assumes gitlab offers the functions I describe by default or they must be implemented by someone capable (in your assumedly self-hosted gitlab), which would result in a gitlab fork which in the long run is probably a bad idea. That being said:

## naive approach

On gitlab logout, redirect the user to your symfony logout page (or, to prevent CSRF, a specific logout page with some verifiable token, like a JWT or similar). Since I don't know much about gitlab, I don't know of any gitlab configuration parameter that would allow this.

However, anyone with enough technical knowledge could prevent the redirect and thus still remain logged in.

## more elaborate solution (and technically more sound)

On gitlab logout, **gitlab** (not the browser!) would have to call some API on your Symfony site with a verifiable token to mark the user as logged out. Symfony on the other hand would have to check for that mark on every request (via an EventListener probably) and logout the user in case it's found. It must be unset as soon as the user logs back in via OAuth though.

Technically, gitlab would have to either have a webhook on logouts for this to work without manipulating gitlab itself, otherwise you find yourself in the spot that you would have to add this feature in gitlab (via an extension/plugin/..., if those exist or add the code to gitlab itself, which is a fork and that would be bad in the long run). Another webhook could remove the mark on the user on successful oauth.

Since I don't know much about gitlab itself and how this would be implemented exactly, I won't and can't provide specific instructions on the gitlab side. Gitlab does offer webhooks, but those are more related to events happening with repositories (wiki, pipeline, issues, commits, ...) and nothing related to the users themselves.

On the symfony side, marking someone as logged out and removing the mark when oauth is successful, as well as logging out the user, when the mark is found, is really all there is to do. However, Not a code monkey and this answer already is much too long.

It can be done, but the effort might just not be worth it.